# Can't make element 100% height when using 'display:table' and 'masonry'

Tags: css, height, masonry

I am using masonry to display images.
I wish to have text appear in the middle of each image and to do this I have displayed a parent as table and the child as table-cell.
I can't get the parent wrapper to 100% height.

```
<div class="grid">
 <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
 <div class="grid-item">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="title">
    <h1>Title Here</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 <img src="any-image.jpg"/>
</div>
```

```
.grid-sizer, .grid-item {
   width: 33.333%;
 }
.grid-item {
   float: left;
   overflow:hidden;
   position:relative;
 }
.wrapper {
   display:table;
   position:absolute;
   text-align:center;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
 }
.title {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
 }
.grid-item img {
   display: block;
 }
```

I also understand that if I define the height of `.grid-item` the text will centre but this changes with the viewport size and therefore I cannot define a single size.

Here is a fiddle if it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/j32921b9/

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may suggest you another approach, without using tables.
Add absolute position to your text wrapper add transform it like so:

```
.title {
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   color:#fff;
 }
```

Here [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okx3uh4o/).

Comment: Worked great. Thank you! Here's a codepen with masonry added - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kkXQVA.